# GoJS delete child nodes without knowing parent node's key

Tags: javascript, gojs

I have a goJS diagram with a custom model.  When dropping a node on another node, I link them  when the mouseDrop fires and set the from and to in the link data on the diagram.model:

```
mydiagram.model.addLinkData({ from: oldNodeModel.key, to: dragNodeModel.key });
```

This all works fine.  In my node template I have a custom template which puts a panel around the nodes with a delete button.  This delete button is simply an image with a click event.

Now when I click the delete image/button, I want to delete this now and all its child nodes.

My issue is I cannot find the children.

I have user events like `findNodesOutOf`, which yields no results and `findNodesConnected` which finds parents and child nodes and deletes the lot - which is not what I want.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: You already provided the key to this solution.  In your model you have the from and to node keys.  Why not simply check that?

Comment: I cannot find the child nodes to check the links

Comment: Use a recursive function to check each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the item to delete by using the diagram.selection:

```
var nodeToDelete = mydiagram.selection.iterator.first();
```

Next to find all the children of this node I recommend a recursive function which will do the following:

1. Take in the node you want to delete,
2. Find all the connected nodes to it using mydiagram.getChildrenNodes(nodeToDelete)
3. Itterrate through the cconnected nodes
4. Check if each node is a child, by using the linkNodeModel and checking is the link goes from the currentnode to the child node.
5. Then call the recursive function again with this child node
6. The recursive function will return an array with all child nodes

Then you can delete them.

Your code will look something like this:

```
function deleteNode()
{
    // TAKE NOTE - This will get all selections so you need to handel  this
    // If you have multiple select enabled
    var nodeToDelete = mydiagram.selection.iterator.first();    
    var childNodes = getChildNodes(deletedItem);

    //Remove linked children
    $.each(childNodes, function()
    {
         myDiagram.remove(this);
    });

    // Then also delete the actual node after the children was deleted
    // TAKE NOTE - This will delete all selections so you need to handle this
    // If you have multiple select enabled
    mydiagram.commandHandler.deleteSelection();
}
```

The recursive function keeps checking each node for its children and adds them to an aray:

```
function getChildNodes(deleteNode)
{
    var children = [];
    var allConnected= deleteNode.findNodesConnected();

    while (allConnected.next())
    {
        var child = allConnected.value;

        // Check to see if this node is a child:
        if (isChildNode(deleteNode, child))
        {
            // add the current child
            children.push(child);

            // Now call the recursive function again with the current child
            // to get its sub children
            var subChildren = getChildrenNodes(child);

            // add all the children to the children array
            $.each(subChildren, function()
            {
                children.push(this);
            });
       }
   }

    // return the children array
    return children;
}
```

This function will check if the node is a child by looking at the links in the diagram and checking to to and from against the current node and child node:

```
function isChildNode(currNode, currChild)
{
    var links = myDiagram.links.iterator;
    while (links.next())
    {
        // Here simply look at the link to determine the direction by checking the direction against the currNode and the child node. If from is the current node and to the child node
        // then you know its a vhild
        var currentLinkModel = links.value.data;
        if (currentLinkModel.from === currNode.data.key &&   currentLinkModel.to === currChild.data.key)
        {
             return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: mm I would not have thought to use a recursive function, im not too familiar with them but it works so thanks.